# Redirecting in JSP from servlet and JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have 2 queries

1)I have a login.jsp page and and index page.Once I authenticate the user(in the servlet ie `check.java`) the user is redirected to the index.jsp page.I redirect it using this line from the servlet

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This process works fine.But when I **refresh** the page I get redirected back to the login page.
Also I have noticed on the index.jsp page I get the name `check` instead of index.jsp,i.e my **servlet** name gets displayed.for example like this
`localhost:8080/abc/check` gets displayed instead of `localhost:8080/abc/index.jsp`

2)On the index page I have 4 different divs,when I click on a div using jquery I get redirected to a page(kind of tabs) but it isnt working
This is my code<%

```
  ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
  URL resourceUrl = sc.getResource("/WEB-INF/admin/logindetails.jsp");
  String path = resourceUrl.toString();
%>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wid7').click(function(){
        var path = <%=path%>;
        document.location.href=path;
    });
});
```

I cant get to the logindetails.jsp

This is my structure

```
-Webcontent
--resources
---js
---css
--Web-Inf
---admin
----index.jsp
----logindetails.jsp
--login.jsp
```

Comment: which method are you using GET or POST for your first problem?

Comment: post method i am using

Comment: That is correct. Have a look at this link to create a sample login page http://javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/

Answer (score 1):

First of all please ask different threads in separate questions. So:

1)`getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`

you structure  is like this

```
login.jsp--(request)-->check.java--(forward(same request))-->index.jsp
```

means your index.jsp is depend on the request came from login.jsp, it's not a separate request that's why it's showing **Check** in URL and when you are doing *refresh* it's generating the new request(not came from login.jsp) that's why showing *login.jsp*.

If you want to change this behavior then use **sendRedirect** instead of **forward** then it will create a new request after *check.java*

**Edit:** Try this:

```
  ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
  URL resourceUrl = sc.getResource("/WEB-INF/admin/login.jsp");
  String path = resourceUrl.toString();
  response.sendRedirect(path);
```

Comment: use sendRedirect for your issue. You can use this link http://javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/

Comment: but using sendredirect i cannot access in web-inf..isnt it?

Comment: you can do everything by sendredirect but it will create a new request only.

Comment: the login page is in webcontent whereas rest of the files including index is in web-inf which i cannot access with sendredirect

Comment: nothing happens..The first time i clicked it remained on the same page and again when i clicked it threw me validation alerts(enter username,etc)

Comment: i think it wud be better for me i guess to keep my jsp files parallel to web-inf instead of inside it..

Comment: If you are using simple frame work then it's good to keep them parallel but in case of other FW's like sping MVC views should be keep in WEF-INF for security.